# OnDeserialized with xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I've been trying to implement the OnDeserialized attribute in a method inside a class.
After I deserialize the class with XmlSerializer the method is never called.

Is OnDeserialized method called even when the serialized class is a member property of the main class being serialized?

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML Serializer does not use OnDeserialized or OnSerialized. It also doesn't use the [Serializable] attribute, BTW.

Comment: Is there another way to acomplish the same?

Comment: Yes. Implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface and do all the work yourself.

Comment: Do you need control over the exact format of the XML? If not, then look at the DataContractSerializer, which may be more extensible than the XML Serializer.

Comment: The problem with DataContractSerializer is that doesn't support attributes and I needed the OnDeserialized benefits only for 1 property. I have very complex elements that I don't want to use IXmlSerializable for.